# Storing a folder hierachy laravel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

I am currently in the process of building a application that allows users to log in and collaborate on a project. I have used laratrust so that I can integrate roles and permissions. What I would like to be able to do is to allow users to create a folder structure however they wish. Just how would I store this as each user could have their own folder structure.

Comment: Can you add a little bit of context? What's this folder hierachy about? Is it in form of UI sortable stuff in the browser?

Comment: Say for example you logged into google drive. You have the abilty to make a folder. And go inside and create more folders etc. A user is connected to a project. If a user is a admin they can create folders within a projects so it could contain anything like: drawings , engineers , etc... @GiamPy

Comment: Are **all** the folders unique for every user, or something is also shared?

Comment: @GiamPy Users are assigned to a project. If a user has a admin privilege they are then able to add/edit/delete folders from the project structure. Standard users who are invited to work on the project are only able to read and view documents within the folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give my 2 cents.

I'd create a new table in the database composed of the following columns with some data examples:

`id | project_id | parent_id | name
 1 |          1 |      null | Main Folder
 2 |          1 |         1 | Child Folder
 3 |          1 |         2 | Child of Child Folder
 4 |          2 |      null | Main Folder Hehe
 5 |          2 |         4 | Child Folder Hehe`

In this way you're going to build a node-based tree, and you can easily build a tree by using such a structure.

Take note that, if the parent_id is null, it means that it has no parent, or in other words, it's one of the base folders of the project.

You can also add a sort column in the table, if you want to share sorts across the project/users!

You will now be able to associate files to every single folder without any issues at all.

Comment: Thank you so much! @GiamPy!